# how to make horizontal sub menu in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

my main menu has a sub menu that is vertically in default.how can i change it to horizontal . the css for sub menu in stylesheet.css is :

```css
.main-nav>ul>li .sub-menu> li {
    padding:0 20px;
}
.main-nav>ul>li .sub-menu> li:first-child>a{
    border:none;
}
.main-nav > ul > li .sub-menu > li >a {
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    color: #666;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
}
.main-nav > ul > li > a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-weight: 700;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
}
```

Comment: You need to post the html to make a working example.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to answer your question without knowing your whole code, however i think what you want is that your li tags should be next to each other instead of below.

If that is the case try adding

```
display: inline-block;
```

to your li tags.